# How to create C# class model for the following json string?

Tags: json, class

How to convert json string to its respective class model for the below example.

Please tell how to convert of indexing of json  to class model `"1": {`

```
{
    "caller_audio": {
        "errors": [],
        "lattice": {
            "1": {
                "links": {
                    "0": {
                        "start": 0,
                        "end": 0.44,
                        "weight": 0,
                        "word_confidence": 0.974111,
                        "best_path": true,
                        "word": "!ENTER",
                        "intensity": 0
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For convert of indexing of json to class model "1": { should use IList.

```
public class LatticeModel
{
    public IList<LinksModel> Links { get; set; }
}
public  class LinksItemModel
{
     public string start { get; set; }

    public string end { get; set; }

    public string weight { get; set; }

    public string word_confidence { get; set; }

    public string best_path { get; set; }

    public string word { get; set; }

    public string intensity { get; set; }

}

public class LinksModel
{

    public IList<LinksItemModel> links { get; set; }
}
```